# Div positioning flooding menu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position a div that contains my google calendar but it keeps flooding my menu.

How do I make it so that the div is positioned more down on the page?

http://lichfieldrooms.uk/calendar.html

Comment: Do you really want a menu with `postion:fixed`, there is other way to make this menu at this position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to remove the position fixed on your header and `.menu` class.

```
.menu {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #e6e6e6;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    //position: fixed; ////remove this////
    top: 85px;
    z-index: 99;
}

Header {
    border-bottom: 0 solid #eee;
    overflow: auto;
    //position: fixed; ////and remove this////
    width: 100%;
}
```

Final code:

```
.menu {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #e6e6e6;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 85px;
    z-index: 99;
}

Header {
    border-bottom: 0 solid #eee;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant thank you! How do I posistion the div down slightly more though?

Comment: You can try giving to the .menu a `margin-bottom` of 50px for example.